# Need to add upper bound to the function which waits to do some operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

There is one function which checks list containing items in it or not. if there are any items in list it will wait for 5 seconds and check that list again in while loop.

Given below is the example :

```
from time import sleep

def list_unfinished_jobs():
    ''' Any operation performed it creates jobs and
        IDs of jobs gets fetch in get_jobs() method
        :return : list of job ids or None if no jobs found 
    '''
    jobs =  get_jobs() # ['JID_1213133', 'JID_3131314', 'JID_23242242'] 
    return jobs

def wait_for_job_completion():
    while list_unfinished_jobs():
        sleep(5)
```

Now i have a scenario in which operation can get stuck and jobs cannot be completed and get_jobs() will never get empty.

So i have written one logic which its checks 20 times whether jobs has been completed or not. Each time it sleeps for 5 secs and i decrease the amount of time at the time of iteration. Below is the code:

```
def wait_for_job_completion(node):
    """Wait for job to complete

    :param node: an ironic node object.
    """
    retries = 20
    while retries > 0:
        if not list_unfinished_jobs(node):
            return
        if list_unfinished_jobs(node):
            sleep(wait_clock)
        retries -= 1
        if retries == 0:
            err_msg = "Timed out waiting for the job to clear"
            LOG.error(err_msg)
            raise exception.DracOperationError(error=msg)
```

I need some another approach to check any function for n times to perform n operation.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please read how to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say why you want a different way of doing this. But if it's a matter of shortening the code, there's a few "improvements" that can be made.

You don't have to call list_unfinished_jobs twice:

```
 if not list_unfinished_jobs(node):
        return
 else:
        sleep(wait_clock)
```

Using a for loop also makes a bit more sense here:

```
for attempt in range(20):
        if not list_unfinished_jobs(node):
            return
        else:
            sleep(wait_clock)
err_msg = "Timed out waiting for the job to clear"
LOG.error(err_msg)
raise exception.DracOperationError(error=msg)
```